# Using NOLINT to suppress clang-tidy. How can I suppress the suppression?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I have code like the following

```
int do_thing( int arg1, int arg2, int arg3 ) { // NOLINT : don't care that arg2 and arg3 aren't used
  return arg1;
}
```

the NOLINT comment suppresses a clang-tidy warning normally.  However, how can I 'reenable' clang-tidy for that line w/o changing my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to do this the way you want. Whenever clang-tidy finds the NOLINT comment, it just skips that line, there is no command-line option to prevent this behavior.

Since NOLINT is placed in comments, you cannot use preprocessor as comments are stripped before macro expansion.

What you can do is find and replace `// NOLINT` with some other (preferably unique) text like `// DISABLE_NOLINT`, run your clang-tidy check and then replace it back.

If you **REALLY** don't want to touch that code you can build your own clang-tidy from source where you modify `static bool LineIsMarkedWithNOLINT()` in ClangTidyDiagnosticConsumer.cpp to always return false. Or even make a new command-line option to switch the behavior if that is worth the effort for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `// NOLINT` at all. Just either remove the argument names or make them to a comment. This will silence the compiler and Clang Tidy.

```
int do_thing( int arg1, int /*arg2*/, int /*arg3*/ ) {
  return arg1;
}
```

Another alternative is to use the [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute introduced in C++ 17:

```
int do_thing( int arg1, [[maybe_unused]] int arg2, [[maybe_unused]] int arg3 ) {
  return arg1;
}
```